# Execute as selector if nearest entity has a tag

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to execute a command to an armor stand if the nearest pig has a specific tag.

The commands that I have tried so far...

`execute as @e[type=armor_stand] at @s if entity @e[type=pig,limit=1,sort=nearest,tag=carrot] run <command>`

does not work because it checks if "carrot"-pig exists.

Having a pig with no tag "carrot" between the armor stand and the "carrot"-pig will just result to *test passed*.

`execute as @e[type=armor_stand] at @s as @e[type=pig,limit=1,sort=nearest] if entity @s[tag=carrot] run <command>`

might have worked but it changed the selector.

Comment: What's wrong with the last command exactly?

Comment: I need to execute it as the armor stand, not the pig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `as` parameter to switch executor to the armour stand at the end.

```
execute
  at @e[type=armor_stand,limit=1,sort=nearest]  # Move the location to the armour stand
  as @e[type=pig,limit=1,sort=nearest]          # NEAREST PIG NOW HAS CONTROL
  if entity @s[tag=carrot]                      # If I have the tag carrot, continue to the next step, otherwise stop.
  as @e[type=armor_stand,limit=1,sort=nearest]  # ARMOUR STAND NOW HAS CONTROL
say The nearest pig to me has the carrot tag!
```

The execution position before the last `as` is still at the armour stand, so the selector always finds the armour stand that started, except if there are multiple at the exact same coordinates.

Comment: Using the `as` parameter at the end worked perfectly but there are some flaws in your command. I already edited the command and your answer to perfect the solution to my problem. All I have to do was remove `limit=1` at the first `as` and add `sort=nearest` at the end. Thanks.

Comment: @Robomike Why does `limit=1` not work for you? I thought there was only one armour stand you were dealing with. But if there are more, removing `limit=1` is certainly needed.